# OpenVPN not working well on specific ISPs

Tags: openvpn

I have a well configured ClearOS server that provides OpenVPN connectivity and Samba shares. I am able to connect to the server via VPN and view the shares with no issues. However, when the client is connected via certain ISPs (Internet Service Provider), VPN behaves very differently and incorrectly. I am located in Ottawa, Canada and everything always works perfectly on a DSL connection. However when connected via cable (Rogers), all shares appear as "empty". This only happens when using this particular ISP, regardless of the location.

It is clearly an ISP issue, but is there anything that can be done on the server end to fix this problem? Any thoughts on what exactly is causing the this strange behavior?

Comment: Do you have 2 openvpn instances or is one handling both interfaces?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are asking... I have a server with 1 openvpn instance and a client machine with 1 openvpn instance.

Comment: I need a drawing where I see your interfaces (DSL and cable) and how they are connecting to the SMB store.

Comment: Ok. Server is always on a DSL connection at location A. Client laptop is at location B with DSL connection and everything works perfectly. Moving the laptop to location C where internet is fed via a cable (not DSL) causes problems. Both location B and C have a very basic setup, a DSL or Cable modem and a basic router providing a LAN. I hope this is what you are looking for, if not, please let me know.

Comment: Location A uses pfSense router/firewall and a switch to which the server is connected.

Answer (score 0):

Logs, configs?

You may have problems with your ISP's firewalling when using VPN @ broken location. You should set up openvpn @ port 443/TCP. If it still won't work you can also give a try to push traffic via HTTP proxy to mask it.